# SQL Query: Additional filtering of result rows using inner join

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Given Table_1:

```
| testing | main_val |
| AB      | VAL      |
| EF      | DIP      |
```

and Table_2:

```
| main_val | for_testing |
| VAL      |             |
| VAL      | AB          |
| VAL      | CD          |
| DIP      |             |
| DIP      | GH          |
```

My join query is below:

```
select table1.testing, table1.main_val, table2.for_testing from table_1 table1
inner join table_2 table2 on table1.main_val = table2.main_val
```

I get the following result:

```
| testing | main_val | for_testing |
| AB      | VAL      |             |
| AB      | VAL      | AB          |
| AB      | VAL      | CD          |
| EF      | DIP      |             |
| EF      | DIP      | GH          |
```

My requirement is to get the best "testing match". If the testing and for_testing columns match, then I should retrieve that row. If no matches, choose the empty for_testing row. I need the result to look like:

```
| testing | main_val | for_testing |
| AB      | VAL      | AB          |
| EF      | DIP      |             |
```

More columns will be added for this join, that is why getting the best match row is important.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select table1.testing, table1.main_val, table2.for_testing 
from table_1 table1
inner join table_2 table2 on table1.main_val = table2.main_val 
where table1.testing =table2.for_testing 
union 
select table1.testing, table1.main_val, table2.for_testing 
from table_1 table1
inner join table_2 table2 on table1.main_val = table2.main_val 
where not in (select table1.testing, table1.main_val, table2.for_testing 
from table_1 table1
inner join table_2 table2 on table1.main_val = table2.main_val 
where table1.testing =table2.for_testing ) and t2.for_testing =""
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will return to me 2 rows, with the column match and the for_testing = "". I tried this already before posting the question, my requirement is not to look for empty string matches if a test-for_testing match was already found.

Comment: @MichaelSanchez Have changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT 
        t1.*,
        t2.For_Testing,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() 
                OVER(
                    PARTITION BY t1.Main_Val 
                    ORDER BY 
                        CASE 
                            WHEN t1.Testing = t2.For_Testing THEN 1
                            WHEN t2.For_Testing = '' THEN 2
                            ELSE 999
                        END
                    )
    FROM Table_1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table_2 t2
        ON t2.MAIN_val = t1.Main_Val
)
SELECT
    Testing,
    Main_val,
    For_Testing
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY Testing
```

Comment: With this approach I no longer get the empty for_testing matches, which I need. I also yield the same results from this approach using left join or inner join.

Comment: So, you want to return every `main_val` from `Table_1`? If it has a match on `testing = for_testing` then select that, else use the empty one?

Comment: All main_val's should only have exactly 1 for_testing associated to it, given the "best match". With the RN where, this would not give me the result that I need. @Jens' union suggestion could work, but the query would be so long :( I'm thinking of doing the final filtering in Java instead.

Comment: Could you update your sample data with duplicate? I get the expected results with your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Left Join and also add for_testing in the joining.

Comment: A description of why would have made this answer so much more useful. Also if you had tested it, you would have seen that it would not produce the require result, at least not from the input shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

This is work for me

```
select Table_1.testing,Table_1.main_val,Table_2.for_testing from Table_2 right join

 Table_1 on Table_2.main_val=Table_1.main_val and Table_2.for_testing=Table_1.testing
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT table1.testing, table1.main_val, table2.for_testing 
FROM table_1 table1 INNER JOIN table_2 table2 
ON table1.main_val = table2.main_val
WHERE table1.testing = table2.for_testing
OR table1.testing IS NULL;
```

I think this can help you.